# How can I fix my Vue component to properly show my Vue-Chart.js line chart?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

I would like to create a line chart using the vue-chartjs library.

What I have created so far produces no error but it also renders nothing but a blank canvas.  When I switch to the developer view, I notice that all my data prints out.  I'm just not sure why it's not rendering.

Here's my HTML and a snippet of the Vue code:

```
<div class="app">
    <h1>Line Chart</h1>
    <line-chart></line-chart>
</div>


<script>

Vue.component('line-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Line,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({          
      labels: this.chartDate,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: this.expectedFund
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello World',
        dataSetData: [],
        expectedFund: '',
        chartDate: '',
        crossOver: '',
        billing: ''     
  },
    methods: {
    getDataSet: function(dataField) {
      console.log("get data sets");
      console.log(this.dataSetData);

      this.expectedFund = this.dataSetData.map(function(chartData) {        
                //alert("expected");
        console.log(chartData);
        return chartData.ExpectedFund;
      });
        this.billing = this.dataSetData.map(function(chartData) {
          return chartData.Billing;
        });
              this.billing = this.dataSetData.map(function(chartData) {
          return chartData.Billing;
        });
              this.chartDate = this.dataSetData.map(function(chartData) {
          return chartData.date;
        });
              this.crossOver = this.dataSetData.map(function(chartData) {
          return chartData.crossOver;
        });
    },
    getListData: async function() {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/chartData"
      );

      return data;
    }
  },
  mounted: async function() {
    this.dataSetData = await this.getListData();
    console.log("ok", this.dataSetData);
    this.getDataSet();
  }
})

</script>
```

If the pasted code is not enough, here's the [Pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/oNvxbKO?editors=1010)

Comment: are you using vue-chartjs? https://vue-chartjs.org/  it will handle this for you so you basically just provide data and options.

Comment: I am actually trying to use that now but am having issues with that as well.

Comment: well if you get stuck with it edit this question and I'll try to help

Comment: Ok. Just did. Thanks

Comment: it looks here https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#creating-your-first-chart like you need to import the chart from the lib and also that data is the first argument to renderChart

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle and bouncing around a bunch of Vue discords, I was able to figure out how to create a multi-line and bar-chart using Vue-Chartjs.  It was a struggle worth it because I finally understand the use of props and how they work, which is what I was missing with the vuejs charts.  Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/ExYKNrq) showing the solution.

I am posting the json below because my charts use that data found in "my [fake json](https://github.com/isogunro/jsondb/blob/master/db.json) server/[typicode](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)".  It might change in the future, so I'm pasting it here.

```
{"chartData":
    [
        {
            "date":"4/4/2019",
            "totalCount":381,
            "ExpectedFund":191,
            "Funded":290,
            "Billing":125,
            "crossOver":241,
            "AcceptedTotal":515
        },
        {
            "date":"4/11/2019",
            "totalCount":233,
            "ExpectedFund":12,
            "Funded":220,
            "Billing":125,
            "crossOver":211,
            "AcceptedTotal":315
        },
        {
            "date":"4/18/2019",
            "totalCount":542,
            "ExpectedFund":34,
            "Funded":240,
            "Billing":125,
            "crossOver":125,
            "AcceptedTotal":415
        },
        {
            "date":"4/25/2019",
            "totalCount":154,
            "ExpectedFund":49,
            "Funded":210,
            "Billing":243,
            "crossOver":35,
            "AcceptedTotal":115
        },
        {
            "date":"5/2/2019",
            "totalCount":300,
            "ExpectedFund":55,
            "Funded":200,
            "Billing":125,
            "crossOver":145,
            "AcceptedTotal":105
        },
        {
            "date":"5/9/2019",
            "totalCount":231,
            "ExpectedFund":55,
            "Funded":250,
            "Billing":125,
            "crossOver":355,
            "AcceptedTotal":215
        },
        {
            "date":"5/16/2019",
            "totalCount":331,
            "ExpectedFund":77,
            "Funded":270,
            "Billing":312,
            "crossOver":15,
            "AcceptedTotal":615
        },
        {
            "date":"5/23/2019",
            "totalCount":498,
            "ExpectedFund":232,
            "Funded":270,
            "Billing":312,
            "crossOver":15,
            "AcceptedTotal":615
        },
        {
            "date":"5/30/2019",
            "totalCount":102,
            "ExpectedFund":33,
            "Funded":150,
            "Billing":25,
            "crossOver":155,
            "AcceptedTotal":315
        },
        {
            "date":"6/6/2019",
            "totalCount":293,
            "ExpectedFund":235,
            "Funded":170,
            "Billing":112,
            "crossOver":125,
            "AcceptedTotal":315
        },
        {
            "date":"6/13/2019",
            "totalCount":198,
            "ExpectedFund":432,
            "Funded":470,
            "Billing":112,
            "crossOver":315,
            "AcceptedTotal":215
        }
    ]
}
```